# JQuery Mobile how to enable a collapsible set to drag and drop

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have tried to get the following demo working using a collapsible set instead of a listview and I am unable to do so:

http://forresst.github.io/2012/06/22/Make-a-list-jQuery-Mobile-sortable-by-drag-and-drop/

Once the collapsible set is made sortable, the collapse functionality gets broken.

I am using:

JQuery Mobile 1.4.5

JQuery 1.11.0

JQuery-UI 1.11.4

Cordova 6.3.0

And I'm testing this on Android (SGS4)

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page" id="test">

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">

        <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" class="sortable">
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 1</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3>Section 3</h3>
            <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /test page -->
```

JavaScript:

```
        $(document).on("pageshow","#test",function(){

            $( ".sortable" ).sortable();
            $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
            /// Refresh list to the end of sort to have a correct display
            $( ".sortable" ).bind( "sortstop", function(event, ui) {
                $('.sortable').collapsibleset('refresh');
//                $('.sortable').listview('refresh');
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

pageshow event not firing. Go through the following code, it is working perfectly.

HTML code:

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>Drag and Drop</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div data-role="page" id="test">

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">

        <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" class="sortable">
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 1</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3>Section 3</h3>
            <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /test page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $(".sortable").sortable();
            $(".sortable").disableSelection();
            /// Refresh list to the end of sort to have a correct display
            $(".sortable").bind( "sortstop", function(event, ui) {
                $('.sortable').collapsibleset('refresh');
//                $('.sortable').listview('refresh');
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Naresh, but this still does not work. As soon as I import the touch-punch script, the collapsible divs no longer collapse and expand. Pageshow worked fine for me. This is a cordova project, maybe that's affecting it?

Comment: I didn't check it in cordova, I have checked in browser and it is working fine @ModusPwnens

Comment: That's why pageshow didn't work for you, pageshow works fine for me. Thanks for your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help someone else out. I have not been able to get a collapsible set to work correctly with drag and drop functionality in cordova, so I came up with a different method. I just placed buttons on the collapsible header so that they can move up or down. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="lib/jqm/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="lib/jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jsignature/jSignature.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="test">

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">

        <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" class="sortable ui-collapsible-set ui-group-theme-a ui-corner-all" data-enhanced="true">

            <div data-role="collapsible" id="collapsible-1" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed" data-enhanced="true">
                <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
                    <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">Section 1<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="span-move-up">
                        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" class="move-collapsible-up circular-btn ui-icon-arrow-u">
                            <span class="ui-icon-arrow-u ui-btn-icon-right" style="float: right;"></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                    <span class="span-move-down">
                        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" class="move-collapsible-down circular-btn ui-icon-arrow-d">
                            <span class="ui-icon-arrow-d ui-btn-icon-right" style="float: right;"></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </h3>
                <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-a ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
                    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="collapsible" id="collapsible-2" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed" data-enhanced="true">
                <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
                    <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">Section 2<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="span-move-up">
                        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" class="move-collapsible-up circular-btn ui-icon-arrow-u">
                            <span class="ui-icon-arrow-u ui-btn-icon-right" style="float: right;"></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                    <span class="span-move-down">
                        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" class="move-collapsible-down circular-btn ui-icon-arrow-d">
                            <span class="ui-icon-arrow-d ui-btn-icon-right" style="float: right;"></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </h3>
                <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-a ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
                    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="collapsible" id="collapsible-3" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed" data-enhanced="true">
                <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
                    <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">Section 3<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="span-move-up">
                        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" class="move-collapsible-up circular-btn ui-icon-arrow-u">
                            <span class="ui-icon-arrow-u ui-btn-icon-right" style="float: right;"></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                    <span class="span-move-down">
                        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" class="move-collapsible-down circular-btn ui-icon-arrow-d">
                            <span class="ui-icon-arrow-d ui-btn-icon-right" style="float: right;"></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </h3>
                <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-a ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
                    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 3</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="collapsible" id="collapsible-4" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed" data-enhanced="true">
                <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
                    <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">Section 4<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="span-move-up">
                        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" class="move-collapsible-up circular-btn ui-icon-arrow-u">
                            <span class="ui-icon-arrow-u ui-btn-icon-right" style="float: right;"></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                    <span class="span-move-down">
                        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" class="move-collapsible-down circular-btn ui-icon-arrow-d">
                            <span class="ui-icon-arrow-d ui-btn-icon-right" style="float: right;"></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </h3>
                <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-a ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
                    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 4</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /test page -->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.circular-btn {
    width: 40px !important;
    height: 40px !important;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.circular-btn span span {
    height: 100px !important;  
    line-height: 70px;
}

.span-move-up {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    float: right;
    top: -22px;
    left: -40px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.move-collapsible-up').on('tap',function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var currCollapseElem = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    var prevCollapseElem = currCollapseElem.prev('div');

    /// detach and attach the add button
    currCollapseElem.insertBefore(prevCollapseElem);

    $('.sortable').collapsibleset('refresh');
});

$('.move-collapsible-down').on('tap',function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var currCollapseElem = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    var nextCollapseElem = currCollapseElem.next('div');

    /// detach and attach the add button
    currCollapseElem.insertAfter(nextCollapseElem);

    $('.sortable').collapsibleset('refresh');
});
```

Again, I hope this helps someone. If I have any issues in my code please don't hesitate to comment.